# Combine two tables to display desired output

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a query which will display projected qty versus qty sold on a monthly basis. Below are my two tables and third one is what i want as an output. The two table is almost the same, except that the date and creation date is in different format (i have converted this to output e.g 201301, so no worries about it). 
As you have noticed in my output table, qty sold become 25.00 because it adds the qty if the date falls under the same month and year. I also need to consider these three important conditions:

1. to display  rows with projected qty but without sales (ex. item 206)
2. To display rows without projected qty but with sales (ex. item 312)
3. to display row with projection and with sales (ex. item001 & 040)

I don't know if i have to used join or union to be able to achieve my desired output.

Table A (Sales Table)

```
item     code          Sold       date
001       cust001      10.00     2013-01-20
001       cust001      15.00     2013-01-25 
040       cust045      16.00     2013-04-07
312       cust001      20.00     2013-03-13
```

Table B (Projection Table)

```
item       Custcode    ProjectedQty       Creation Date
001        cust001     20.00              2013-01-01
040        cust045     50.00              2013-04-01
206        cust121     60.00              2013-04-01
```

Output

```
item       Custcode    sold     Date          ProjectedQty         Creation Date
001       cust001      25.00     201301         20.00                 201301
312       cust001      20.00     201303    null                   null
040        cust045    16.00     201304          50.00                 201304
206       cust121      null     null            60.00                 201304
```

Thanks guys for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.item, s.item) item,
       COALESCE(p.code, s.code) code, 
       sold, 
       CONCAT(s.year, LPAD(s.month, 2, '0')) date, 
       ProjectedQty, 
       CONCAT(p.year, LPAD(p.month, 2, '0')) creationdate
FROM 
(
  SELECT item, code, YEAR(`date`) year, MONTH(`date`) month 
    FROM sales
   UNION
  SELECT item, custcode, YEAR(`creationdate`), MONTH(`creationdate`)
    FROM projection
) i LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT item, code, SUM(sold) sold, YEAR(`date`) year, MONTH(`date`) month
    FROM sales
   GROUP BY item, code, YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
) s ON i.item  = s.item 
   AND i.code  = s.code 
   AND i.year  = s.year 
   AND i.month = s.month LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT item, custcode code, SUM(ProjectedQty) ProjectedQty, YEAR(`creationdate`) year, MONTH(`creationdate`) month
    FROM projection
   GROUP BY item, custcode, YEAR(`creationdate`), MONTH(`creationdate`)
) p ON i.item  = p.item 
   AND i.code  = p.code 
   AND i.year  = p.year 
   AND i.month = p.month
ORDER BY code, item
```

Output:

```
| ITEM |    CODE |   SOLD |   DATE | PROJECTEDQTY | CREATIONDATE |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  001 | cust001 |     25 | 201301 |           20 |       201301 |
|  312 | cust001 |     20 | 201303 |       (null) |       (null) |
|  040 | cust045 |     16 | 201304 |           50 |       201304 |
|  206 | cust121 | (null) | (null) |           60 |       201304 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66205/16)**

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple **join** for this?

```
SELECT * FROM `sales`, `projection` WHERE `code`=`custcode`;
```

Make a **view** of the query above, and using `WHERE` clause, you can alter the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view using union. and then you can use the below query:

```
select *, sum(sold) as sold from view group by item
```

another is:

```
select *, sum(sold) from (
select item,       code as Custcode,    sold,     date,          'ProjectedQty' as ProjectedQty,         'Creation Date' as Creation Date from table 1 union select item,       Custcode,    sold,     Date,          ProjectedQty,         Creation Date, from table 2) group by item
```